# Image positioning is not working

Tags: css, image, replace, hyperlink, absolute

I have problem positioning these two buttons on page I'm working on. I'm trying to make image link smaller on click. Looks like absolute positioning doesn't do it's job or something.

Page: http://osuuskuntainfo.orgfree.com/saannot.html

```
<div id="yläreuna">

    <div id="etusivullenappi">

        <img class="bottom" src="/images/etusivullenappix.png" width="100%" />
        <a href="http://osuuskuntainfo.orgfree.com/index.html"><img class="top" src="/images/etusivullenappi.png" width="100%" /></a>

    </div>

    <div id="otsikko"><img src="images/säännöt otsikko.jpg" width="81%" alt="osuuskunnan säännöt" /></div>

    <div id="pelisäännötnappi">

        <img class="bottom" src="/images/pelisäännötnappix.png" width="100%" />
        <a href="#pelisäännöt"><img class="top" src="/images/pelisäännötnappi.png" width="100%" /></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#yläreuna {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

#etusivullenappi {
    position: relative;
    width: 13%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 42px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 8%;
}

#etusivullenappi img {
    -position: absolute;
    -left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0s ease-in-out;
    top: 0px;
}

#etusivullenappi img.top:active {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve... also, images looks pretty bad on higher screen resolutions...

Comment: I haven't got the final images jet. These are just some drafts to make the page work. I'm trying to make link images smaller on click. Now they are doubled on each other.

Comment: `-position: absolute; -left: 0px;`? Why are there dashes there?

Comment: @bjb568 That seems to be the answer, you should post it as one!

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
-position: absolute;
-left: 0px;
```

Presumably a typo from vendor prefixes. That will cause the property to be unknown, and thus not get rendered. You should write:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
```